# SSD and rapid storage techology

Tags: drivers, ssd, intel-rst

I have one ssd (samsung evo 250 GB  ,on which is installed the the OS, and it's  configured with samsung magician, which has AHCI mode enabled and it's linked to a 6gb/s sata interface. I have only these driver installed made by intel:

- intel(R) 7 series chipset family sata ahci controller
- intel(R) 7 series/C216 chipset family pci express root port

and other driver intel for usb purpose.

do i need to install the intel rapid storage driver for boost my ssd?

Can someone explain me why this driver is used,because i searched on internet, but i' m a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel Rapid Storage Technology is a raid software, a few other assitive programs, and ACHI drivers that can be used
for 1 or more drives.
Since you only have 1 drive you cannot get any of the benifits of raid. The only performance boost you could
get would be from it's NCQ support and power setting alterations. If you are using a newer Windows operating system like Windows 7, and installed the OS
under ACHI mode then you already have NCQ support from the Windows drivers. If you are running an older
operating system like Windows XP then you don't have NCQ support, but if your storage controller, and SSD support NCQ then
using Intel Rapid Storage Technology could provide a performance boost. Intel's Rapid Storage Technology also
includes a program called Dynamic Storage Accelerator, which adjusts your power settings to provide max power
to the drive when needed. If you normally don't have your OS's power settings setup to provide maximum drive
performance then you could see a performance increase using Rapid Storage Technology under certain workloads.

## Sources:

> Intel® Rapid Storage Technology offers new levels of protection, performance and expandability 
> for desktop and mobile platforms. Whether using one or multiple hard drives

- http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-020784.htm

> Intel Rapid Storage Technology provides benefits to users of single drives as well. 
> Through AHCI, storage performance is improved with Native Command Queuing (NCQ)

- http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-020784.htm

> [NCQ] allows ATA drives to accept more than one command at a time and dynamically reorder 
> the commands for maximum efficiency.

- http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-012305.htm

> Dynamic storage accelerator [...] dynamically adjusting system power management policies to deliver up to 15 percent 
> faster performance1 during heavy multitasking compared to default power management.

- http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html

> [NCQ] can reduce the amount of unnecessary drive head movement, resulting in increased performance

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing

> Windows 7's AHCI [driver] enables not only NCQ but also TRIM support

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing

> Older operating systems such as Windows XP require the installation of a vendor-specific driver [for NCQ support]

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing

> NCQ is also used in newer solid-state drives where the drive encounters latency on the host

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, well,i have only one drive and i use as power management, the samsung high performance, this option was created by samsung magician,the software that manage the ssd.So i don't need to download the rapid storage right?

Comment: @oIrC "So I don't need to download the rapid storage right?" Correct, you don't need it.

Comment: How do you adjust the Windows 10 power settings setup to provide maximum drive performance? You just have to go whole hog and set the Power Options to "High performance", or is there a more granular option?